# Why this c code is not accepting input from when i am running this code. this program is getting exist without taking any input

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 

main()
{
    int t,i;
    scanf("%d",&t);

    check();
    return 0;
}

int check()
{ 
    char s[20];
    gets(s);

    printf("%s",s);
    return 1;
}
```

When I run this check function, this function does not take input and immediately exits. I don't know why please tell me

Comment: Never ever use `scanf` without checking its return value.

Comment: Please see [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a space character following the `%d` in scanf to read in the whitepace that follows the value entered.

In other words, use:

```
scanf("%d ", &t);
```

Also note that `gets` has been deprecated for years. It is vulnerable to buffer overrun attacks. Use `fgets` instead.

Here is a fixed version of this program:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

#define CHECK_BUFSIZE 19

int check()
{ 
    char s[CHECK_BUFSIZE+1];
    fgets(s, CHECK_BUFSIZE, stdin);
    printf("%s",s);
}

int main()
{
    int t,i;
    scanf("%d ",&t);   
    check();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Your `CHECK_BUFSIZE` in combination with the `fgets` is wrong. Instead, you can/should use `char s[20]; fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin); printf("%s",s);` optionally having `20` be the value of a macro.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration of the function is must if you write it after main function.
gets has been deprecated so, scanf is a better variant .

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int check();
main()
{
    int t,i;
    scanf("%d",&t);

    check();
    return 0;
}

int check()
{ 
    char s[20];
    scanf("%s",s);

    printf("%s",s);
    return 1;
}
```

Also if you want string input with spaces in it then use "%[^\n]" instead of using "%s" in the scanf function

Comment: "gets has been deprecated so, scanf is a better variant ."  To the best of my knowledge, scanf with %s is no better than gets.

Comment: i mentioned it in the answer earlier, if one needs to add space in a string then use scanf with  "%[^\n]" ,that might be better then gets function .

Comment: gets is deprecated because it has overflow problems.  scanf with %s has the same problem, so it is not a better variant.  See [What can I use for input conversion instead of scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58403537).